# Edwards Calculus chapter 4 problem 81

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I can see that the terms arise from the differentiation of $\log(1+x^{2^r} )$ and tried to do it but couldn't figure it out in the end.

> Show that
>   $$
> \frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{2x}{1+x^2} + \frac{4x^3}{1+x^4} + \frac{8x^7}{1+x^8} + \ldots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n} x^{(2^n -1)}}{1+x^{(2^n)}} =  \frac{1}{1-x} \qquad \text{when}~|x|<1
> $$

Comment: What a weirdly worded question, it contains grammatical errors and quite bad mathematical notation. Not good for the publisher of the book ...

Comment: Is the question asking to show that
$$
\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{2x}{1+x^2} + \frac{4x^3}{1+x^4} + \frac{8x^7}{1+x^8} + \ldots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n x^{(2^n -1)}}{1+x^{(2^n)}} =  \frac{1}{1-x} \qquad \text{when}~|x|<1
$$
?

Comment: @MattiP. Yeah that's the question

Comment: As a native English speaker, this question is painful to read @MattiP.

Comment: @AugustaASAKA This site does not like images of math. Please learn to use formatting. There is an excellent guide [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?newreg=41e9c3e89a6e404d956d87b21d8c62b6)

Comment: @almagest Sorry, I would remember that next time

Comment: @scoopfaze English is not my native language too and all i care about is the problem and the fact that atleast I can understand the what's asked from me.

Comment: @AugustaASAKA, I appreciate that. I was just making a joke in light of what Matti P. said is all.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume 
$$S=\dfrac{1}{1+x}+\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{4x^3}{1+x^4}+...$$
The common term of the series, as seen from the pattern, is $\displaystyle \frac{2^{n} x^{(2^n -1)}}{1+x^{(2^n)}}$ for $n=0,1,2,3,...$ and the sum is then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n} x^{(2^n -1)}}{1+x^{(2^n)}}$.

Now, noting that the numerator in each case is the derivative of the denominator, as you've already done, we integrate $$\int_0^x Sdx=\left[\ln(1+x)+\ln(1+x^2)+\ln(1+x^4)+...\right]^x_0$$
$$=\ln[(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)...]$$
$$=\ln(1+x+x^2+x^3...)$$

Here, $\ln$ denotes the natural logarithm and I've used the facts that for the lower limit, $\ln1=0$, then $\ln a+\ln b= \ln{ab}$ and expanded the multiplication in the last step.
Note that the series $1+x+x^2+x^3+...$ is the series expansion of $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ and this is valid only when $|x|<1$. So the term inside the logarithm converges provided that $|x|<1$ and the sum is $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$.

Thus, $\displaystyle\int_0^x Sdx=\ln {\dfrac{1}{1-x}}$ and so,

$$ S=\dfrac{d}{dx} \ln\left( \dfrac{1}{1-x} \right)=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$